# Binding to a specific path of ValueConverter returned object

Tags: c#, wpf

I am wondering if there is any way to bind to a specific property of an object a converter(IValueConverter) is returning

For example

```
public class MyObject
{

      public Uri MyUri{get;set;}
     //.................

}

public class SomeConverter:IValueConverter
{
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,            
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
          {
                IService service = (IService )value;
                return new MyObject(service, parameter.ToString());
           }
 }
```

Intented usage: Pass in service from UI. Bind to the "MyUri" property of MyObject

```
BackgroundGraphic="{Binding MyService, Path=MyUri,Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, ConverterParameter="Image1"}" //Will not work
```

Only pseudo code above

Comment: You don't bind to the value returned by the converter. the converter converts the value of the bound property.

Comment: Edited the post. Hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

Well, no. You bind to *one* property - you could indeed bind to several properties using a multi converter but that's another story - specified by the Path property of the Binding and you get back *one* converted value from the converter.

There is no way to bind, convert and then bind again to something else using the same binding.

A converter is probably not what you want here. You better expose the converted value directly through a property of your view model and then bind to a sub-property of this one:

**View Model:**

```
//existing property:
public IService MyService { get { return _service; } }

//new property. Bind to this wrapper property which basically handles the conversion logic:
public MyObject MyObject { get { return new MyObject(_service); }}
```

**View:**

```
BackgroundGraphic="{Binding MyService.MyUri}"
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to say one thing in the question,  I want to pass in some parameter. The idea is to do the this: BackgroundGraphic="{Binding MyService, Path=MyUri,Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, ConverterParameter="Image1"}". This is to pass in different image names through the mechanism. This way I can change the image path in the background and the image changes are reflected in the view, I will edit the post too

Comment: To be more clear: The UI refer to images like Image1, Image2 like that. In the background from where the image is picked up changes. This mechanism is to refresh the UI when the path changes

Comment: I don't see how this relates to or make any difference your original question. The answer is the same. You *cannot* bind to a (sub)property of a value that is returned from the converter.

Comment: The key difference here is with a converter you can pass a parameter from the UI. Basically I want to pass in a resource name from UI and then get the actual Uri against which I can bind. Its like saying , for a given resource name give me a Uri back against which I can bind.